# Python: CLI special characters

Tags: python

I've recently learned that `_` refers to the last output in command line (IDLE too). Are there other special characters that I should be aware of? I find the `_` trick really useful.

Example:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> x
4
>>> _
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `_` is the only "magic" variable in an interactive command-line session (or IDLE).

Comment: @MattDMo Certainly. I'm not familiar with IPython, so I restricted my answer to the standard interpreter. If you'd like, an answer about IPython's magic would be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

In interactive mode, you can use `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` etc for doing arithmetic operations and which will give you result in `STDOUT`

```
>>> 2 * 2
4
>>> _ + 7
11
>>> _ + 2
13
>>> 4 + 1
5
```

In script mode if you want result in `STDOUT`, you have to specifically write it on `STDOUT` like using `print` statement.

Comment: I would just point out that using `print` in a script would not necessarily result with the same output, because `print` displays `str(x)` while the interactive shell displays `repr(x)`.